# How to update same ng-select dropdown list

Tags: angular9

I have ng-select in Angular 9
when clicking on any item in ng-select dropdown list need to get an update

```
    <ng-select
    formControlName="postalCode"
    id="postalCode{{ idSuffix }}"
    [items]="locations"
    [selectOnTab]="true"
    [loading]="postalCodeLoading"
    typeToSearchText="Please enter 2 or more characters"
    [typeahead]="searchInput$"
    [editableSearchTerm]="true"
    (change) = "getValues($event)"
  >
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
      <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{ item.address.formattedAddress }}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
```

here is ts file code

```
 getValues($event){
console.log($event)
this.locations.length = 0
for (let index = 0; index < $event.ranges.length; index++) {
  const range = $event.ranges[index];
  // console.log(range.units[0].formattedUnitAddress)
  const location = {} as Location
  location.address = {} as Address
  location.address.formattedAddress = range.units[0].formattedUnitAddress
  this.locations.push(location)
}
console.log("*****")
console.log(this.locations.length)
```

but above code not updating the list, also list should be there when clicking on any item, now its getting disappear

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? What value of locations.length is being output? What is the value of $event.ranges? Something is probably causing this.locations to become empty, or add nulls, so maybe step through your code with the debugger, and see which line is messing up the array.

Comment: no not getting error ..I have added partial cod here, no values are empty or null

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What exactly is happening? What does 'now it's getting disappear' mean? The whole select is disappearing? Or just there are no items in it. You are updating the locations array. How many items do you end up with in this.locations when it disappears? If it's not empty, what is the value of .adddress.formattedAddress on each item in the array? It's easy to see these things in the dev tools, and it would help to know. Were you following a tutorial? Maybe give the link. Unless someone else is familiar with this exact code, for the rest of us, info would help.

Comment: How to update dropdown list in ng-select when clicking on any item in existing dropdown

Comment: scenario ng-select > dropdown > click on any item > list should update as clicked item has data (should not disappear list ) > need to update list with item's data > then on clicking on item need to appear in ng-select selected value